# Linux kernel 5.4 how to change code that modifies status change time of a file?

Tags: linux, kernel, filemtime

I've found [Setting creation or change timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps), I want to try kernel modification path from the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066309/14557599. However, the answer is 8 years old and as I've checked the user had not posted on SO for several years. The answer says:

> Here is the change to KERNEL_SRC/fs/attr.c in the notify_change
> function:

But there is no link to file location and I was not able to find it via web search, only reposts of that QA. Does kernel still works that way for updating change time? Please help to locate that code in current kernel source to try modification on.

Added 1:

Web search finds `notify_change` in api docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/api-summary.html.
[Best way to find functions in kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987815/best-way-to-find-functions-in-kernel-code) advises to use http://lxr.linux.no, but search for `notify_change` there produced empty result.

I've tried second way from the above answer, downloaded latest from [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org), `cd`-d into folder where I extracted archive, but then:

```
~/Downloads/linux-5.15.12$ make cscope
  GEN     cscope
./scripts/tags.sh: line 126: cscope: command not found
```

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/attr.c#L310 - trivially searchable

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to Stack Overflow

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, thank you for the link, however why is it unrelated to SO as it is software dev (IMO)? What SE site is proper place for such questions?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `grep`:

```
~/Downloads/linux-5.15.12$ find . -name '*.c' -type f -exec bash -c 'grep " notify_change(" {} && ls -l {} && echo' \;
```

I found the code where one could have guessed it should be: `./fs/attr.c`, that is `KERNEL_SRC` meant root of kernel source folder.